# Group or summarize Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ecmascript-6

```
var json =
[
   {
      id: 11,
      name:"app1",
      family:"apps",
      caseID: 123,
      order:1
   },
   {
      id: 12,
      name:"app1",
      family:"apps",
      caseID: 123,
      order:2
   },
   {
      id: 13,
      name:"app1",
      family:"apps",
      caseID: 123,
      order:3
   },
   {
      id: 14,
      name:"app2",
      family:"tools",
      caseID: 129,
      order:1
   },
   {
      id: 15,
      name:"app2",
      family:"tools",
      caseID: 129,
      order:2
   },
   {
      id: 16,
      name:"app3",
      family:"utils",
      caseID: 120,
      order:1
   },
   {
      id: 17,
      name:"app3",
      family:"utils",
      caseID: 120,
      order:2
   },
      id: 18,
      name:"app3",
      family:"utils",
      caseID: 150,
      order:null
   }
  ]
```

Hello, I would like to sort the array above by the highest "order" key and return the filtered array below. The common key is the caseID. Also, If the order key is null return it.
I've searched and tested some functions and loops but cannot seem to get it rite. Any help will be much appreciated. I'd prefer es2015 if possible.
Thank you!

```
filtered = 
 [

  {
      id: 13,
      name:"app1",
      family:"apps",
      caseID: 123,
      order:3  
   },
   {
      id: 15,
      name:"app2",
      family:"tools",
      caseID: 129,
      order:2
   },
   {
      id: 17,
      name:"app3",
      family:"utils",
      caseID: 120,
      order:2
   },
   {
      id: 18,
      name:"app3",
      family:"utils",
      caseID: 150,
      order:null
   }
  ]
```

Comment: I see no effort involved.

Comment: Also, question doesn't explain the logic to determine the output from input. Output is missing many elements from input.

Comment: Do you mean this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aGypVE?editors=0010 ?

Comment: Thank you Everyone for replying. I will be going through all of the answers to learn a thing or 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by getting rid of dupes. You can do this with `reduce()` and assigning to an object keyed to `caseID`. You can simultaneously avoid any object with a smaller `order` than one you've already seen. Then you can take the values of that hash which will be the unique objects base on `caseID` and sort them like you normally would. For example:

```js
var json = [{   "id": 11,   "name":"app1",   "family":"apps",   "caseID": 123,   "order":1},{   "id": 12,   "name":"app1",   "family":"apps",   "caseID": 123,   "order":2},{   "id": 13,   "name":"app1",   "family":"apps",   "caseID": 123,   "order":3},{   "id": 14,   "name":"app2",   "family":"tools",   "caseID": 129,   "order":1},{   "id": 15,   "name":"app2",   "family":"tools",   "caseID": 129,   "order":2},{   "id": 16,   "name":"app3",   "family":"utils",   "caseID": 120,   "order":1},{   "id": 17,   "name":"app3",   "family":"utils",   "caseID": 120,   "order":2},{   "id": 18,   "name":"app3",   "family":"utils",   "caseID": 150,   "order":null},] 

// get just the filtered items based on caseID
// picking out only the largest
let filtered = json.reduce((a,c) => {
      if (!a[c.caseID] || a[c.caseID]['order'] < c.order) a[c.caseID] = c
      return a
  }, {})

// basic sort
let result = Object.values(filtered).sort((a,b) => b.order - a.order)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thank you for a fast reply and explaining the solution. I never thought of breaking it down into 2 pieces. Filter and then sort.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `caseID` hashtable and override results you find later if `order` is higher:

```
  const result = [], hash = {};

  for(const el in json) {
   const exists = hash[el.caseId];
   if(exists) {
     if(el.order > exists.order)
       Object.assign(exists, el);
   } else {
       result.push(hash[el.caseId] = {...el});
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following

**Method**

1. Create an object with unique case ID as key and value being the item with highest order
2. Sort based on order

```js
// Code goes here

var json = [{"id":11,"name":"app1","family":"apps","caseID":123,"order":1},{"id":12,"name":"app1","family":"apps","caseID":123,"order":2},{"id":13,"name":"app1","family":"apps","caseID":123,"order":3},{"id":14,"name":"app2","family":"tools","caseID":129,"order":1},{"id":15,"name":"app2","family":"tools","caseID":129,"order":2},{"id":16,"name":"app3","family":"utils","caseID":120,"order":1},{"id":17,"name":"app3","family":"utils","caseID":120,"order":2},{"id":18,"name":"app3","family":"utils","caseID":150,"order":null}];
  
  
  var map = {};

  // Create a map of unique case ID's with highest order
  json.forEach((item) => {
    if(map[item.caseID]) {
        if(map[item.caseID].order < item.order) {
          map[item.caseID] = item;
        }
    } else {
      map[item.caseID] = item;
    }
  });
  
  // Sorting the array based on order
  var result = Object.values(map).sort((a,b) => b.order-a.order);
  console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

In ES6:

```
json.sort((a, b) => a.caseID > b.caseID);
let bad_order = json.filter(v => v.order === null);
let good_order = json.filter(v => v.order !== null);
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aGypVE?editors=0010)

In ES5:

```
json.sort(function(a, b) { return a.caseID > b.caseID; });

var bad_order = [];
var good_order = [];

for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
  if(json[i].order === null)
    bad_order.push(json[i]);
  else
    good_order.push(json[i]);
}
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ELvZLQ?editors=0010)

Answer (score 0):

Use `reduce` method to create an object where the keys will be the `caseID`.While creating the object check if the value of the order is more or less that the current order value.If the current value is less the than the new value, replace it with new value.

Then use `Object.values(object)` to create an array of values from the object

```js
var json = [{
    "id": 11,
    "name": "app1",
    "family": "apps",
    "caseID": 123,
    "order": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 12,
    "name": "app1",
    "family": "apps",
    "caseID": 123,
    "order": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 13,
    "name": "app1",
    "family": "apps",
    "caseID": 123,
    "order": 3
  },
  {
    "id": 14,
    "name": "app2",
    "family": "tools",
    "caseID": 129,
    "order": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 15,
    "name": "app2",
    "family": "tools",
    "caseID": 129,
    "order": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 16,
    "name": "app3",
    "family": "utils",
    "caseID": 120,
    "order": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 17,
    "name": "app3",
    "family": "utils",
    "caseID": 120,
    "order": 2
  }, {
    "id": 18,
    "name": "app3",
    "family": "utils",
    "caseID": 150,
    "order": null
  }
]

var m = json.reduce(function(acc, curr, index) {
  if (acc[curr['caseID']] === undefined) {
    acc[curr['caseID']] = curr;

  } else {
    if (acc[curr['caseID']].order < curr.order) {
      acc[curr['caseID']] = curr;
    }
  }
  return acc;
}, {})
console.log(Object.values(m))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you filter array of objects.

```
            var filteredMap = {};
            json.forEach(function (item) {
                filteredMap[item.caseID] = item;
            });
            var filteredArray = [];
            for (var key in filteredMap) {
                filteredArray.push(filteredMap[key]);
            }
            console.log(JSON.stringify(filteredArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort by order and caseID and then filter by caseID,Here is the code:

```
var json =
[
   {
      id: 11,
      name:"app1",
      family:"apps",
      caseID: 123,
      order:1
   },
   {
      id: 12,
      name:"app1",
      family:"apps",
      caseID: 123,
      order:2
   },
   {
      id: 13,
      name:"app1",
      family:"apps",
      caseID: 123,
      order:3
   },
   {
      id: 14,
      name:"app2",
      family:"tools",
      caseID: 129,
      order:1
   },
   {
      id: 15,
      name:"app2",
      family:"tools",
      caseID: 129,
      order:2
   },
   {
      id: 16,
      name:"app3",
      family:"utils",
      caseID: 120,
      order:1
   },
   {
      id: 17,
      name:"app3",
      family:"utils",
      caseID: 120,
      order:2
   }, {
      id: 18,
      name:"app3",
      family:"utils",
      caseID: 150,
      order:null
   }
 ]
var obj = {}
var arr = json.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b.order - a.order
}).sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.caseId - b.caseId
}).filter(function(item, index, array){
  return obj.hasOwnProperty(item.caseID) ? false : (obj[item.caseID] = true)
})
console.log(arr)
```

demo: http://jsbin.com/qabehorike/edit?js,console,output